# Java inheritance confusion, superclass and subclass member variable having same name

Tags: java, inheritance, this

On running this code

```
class c1 { int ci = 1; }

class c2 extends c1 { int ci = 2; }

class inheritanceTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        c1 c1reftoc2 = new c2();
        System.out.println(c1reftoc2.ci);
    }
}
```

Output is `1`. So i guess that a subclass object with superclass reference variable, uses superclass variable in case of variables of same name in both classes.

But then, running this program from a SCJP question,

```
class Foo {
    public int a = 3;
    public void addFive() {
        a += 5;
        System.out.print("f ");
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public int a = 8;
    public void addFive() {
        System.out.println(this.a);
        this.a += 5;
        System.out.print("b " );
        System.out.println(this.a);
    }
}

class SCJPQC3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Bar();
        f.addFive();
        System.out.println(f.a);
    }
}
```

output is

```
8
b 13
3
```

The `addFive()` method called in `main()` would be that of class `Bar` because of overriding.

`this.a` in `addFive()` prints `8`. Whereas `f.a` in `main()` gives `3`. Instances being referred by `this.` and `f.` are same, yet they give different results. Using `this.a` gives `8` as output which contradicts my previous understanding.

So my question is, does `this.` refer to a class or an instance? I know that `this.` would refer to the object through which a method is called, but this particular program confused me.

Comment: You need to remember this one simple rule: ***fields are not polymorphic, only methods are***. In case of `this` inside code blocks of `SomeClass` you can think of it as `SomeClass this` reference (although it is keyword).

Comment: @Pshemo that does clear some confusion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `this` here refers to the current object instance, on which the method was called.  Because of polymorphishm, `Bar`'s `addFive` method is called.  That method refers to the `a` in scope there, which is `Bar`'s `a`.  (`Bar`'s `a` *hides* `Foo`'s `a`.)  That is why `8` is printed initially, and why it gets changed to `13`.  However, when `System.out.println(f.a);` is called at the end of `main`, the compiler only sees `f` as a `Foo` variable, so it prints `3` -- `Foo`'s `a`, which was never changed from `3`.

Comment: Thanks, I had read about hiding of variables but didn't knew about it being applied in methods. Does the same happen in constructors?

Answer (score 2):

When declaring a variable in a subclass with the same name as in the superclass, you are *hiding* the variable, unlike methods which are overwritten. This difference is since f points to an object of type Bar, the addFive() method in Bar is used. However, when calling f.a, its reference type is Foo and it looks for the variable there first. Hiding variables in subclasses should generally be avoided for this reason.